# WSO2 DAS Dashboard - Delete unused pages

Tags: wso2, wso2-das

I can't delete nor edit pages created in WSO2 DAS Dashboard. The home page works fine with the pre-configured gadgets, but I created 2 new pages and I can't delete them now. I also can't change the name of them, or add gadgets, or anything.

Answer (score 0):

Can you let us know what you see in the browser console when you try to delete them ? Dashboard configuration is saved in the registry as a json and you can edit it and delete the unwanted pages if needed. You can browse the registry from management console. Your created dashboard will be in following registry path

/_system/config/ues/dashboards/yourDashboardName

You will see a pages array as "pages":[].

EDIT:
This solution may work for you :
As mentioned above retrieve the json file and in above pages array in your first page(which is working correctly) you will see a json path as

```
"content":{  
            "default":{
```

Inside that there will be many gadget json configurations starting with a, b ,c etc like below

```
"d":[  
                  {  
                     "id":"OnBoardingRequest-overall-0",
                     "content":{  
                        "id":"OnBoardingRequest-overall",
                        "title":"OnBoardingRequest-overall",
                        "type":"gadget",
                        "thumbnail":"fs://gadget/OnBoardingRequest-overall/thumbnail.png",
                        "data":{  
                           "url":"fs://gadget/OnBoardingRequest-overall/gadget.xml"
                        },
                        "styles":{  
                           "title":"OnBoardingRequest-overall",
                           "borders":true
                        },
                        "options":{  
                           "role":{  
                              "type":"STRING",
                              "title":"Gadet Role",
                              "value":"",
                              "options":[  

                              ],
                              "required":true
                           }
                        },
                        "locale_titles":{  

                        }
                     }
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":"OnBoardingRequest-overall-task-breakdown-0",
                     "content":{  
                        "id":"OnBoardingRequest-overall-task-breakdown",
                        "title":"OnBoardingRequest-overall-task-breakdown",
                        "type":"gadget",
                        "thumbnail":"fs://gadget/OnBoardingRequest-overall-task-breakdown/thumbnail.png",
                        "data":{  
                           "url":"fs://gadget/OnBoardingRequest-overall-task-breakdown/gadget.xml"
                        },
                        "styles":{  
                           "title":"OnBoardingRequest-overall-task-breakdown",
                           "borders":true
                        },
                        "options":{  
                           "role":{  
                              "type":"STRING",
                              "title":"Gadet Role",
                              "value":"",
                              "options":[  

                              ],
                              "required":true
                           }
                        },
                        "locale_titles":{  

                        }
                     }
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":"OnBoardingRequest-overall-task-breakdown-0",
                     "content":{  
                        "id":"OnBoardingRequest-overall-task-breakdown",
                        "title":"OnBoardingRequest-overall-task-breakdown",
                        "type":"gadget",
                        "thumbnail":"fs://gadget/OnBoardingRequest-overall-task-breakdown/thumbnail.png",
                        "data":{  
                           "url":"fs://gadget/OnBoardingRequest-overall-task-breakdown/gadget.xml"
                        },
                        "styles":{  
                           "title":"OnBoardingRequest-overall-task-breakdown",
                           "borders":true
                        },
                        "options":{  
                           "role":{  
                              "type":"STRING",
                              "title":"Gadet Role",
                              "value":"",
                              "options":[  

                              ],
                              "required":true
                           }
                        },
                        "locale_titles":{  

                        }
                     }
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":"OnBoardingRequest-overall-task-breakdown-0",
                     "content":{  
                        "id":"OnBoardingRequest-overall-task-breakdown",
                        "title":"OnBoardingRequest-overall-task-breakdown",
                        "type":"gadget",
                        "thumbnail":"fs://gadget/OnBoardingRequest-overall-task-breakdown/thumbnail.png",
                        "data":{  
                           "url":"fs://gadget/OnBoardingRequest-overall-task-breakdown/gadget.xml"
                        },
                        "styles":{  
                           "title":"OnBoardingRequest-overall-task-breakdown",
                           "borders":true
                        },
                        "options":{  
                           "role":{  
                              "type":"STRING",
                              "title":"Gadet Role",
                              "value":"",
                              "options":[  

                              ],
                              "required":true
                           }
                        },
                        "locale_titles":{  

                        }
                     }
                  }
               ],
```

In those check for id which corresponds to your gadget names and see whether you have a name which you do not have at the moment. May be you have deleted it and now its not using anymore. if its there remove the whole a, or b or what ever the corresponding section. Please take a backup before doing so. Then save it . And it should work. As a workaround you can delete the dashboard and create a new one and add the gadgets. Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, I can delete them in the registry, but I can't edit them in the dashboard editor. I can't even change their name, or press the delete button. When I press the

Comment: Did you see this behavior in a fresh pack ? And you are seeing this after you have done some configurations ?

Comment: All the configuration I did was to create a few simple dashboards, no more than that

Comment: Did u try the solution i mentioned above ? i have edited the answer

Comment: Yes, I tried it, but that is not solving the main problem. Yes, I know I can change the configuration of the dashboard changing the json, but as the administrator of the system, I can´t tell the customers that if they need to change something in the dashboard, they have to dive in some json they dont understand

Comment: Yes its a bug .. we need to fix it. Please create a jira for it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I can delete them in the registry, but I can't edit them in the dashboard editor. I can't even change their name, or press the delete button. When I press the name of the page to expand the settings of the page, it doesn't show anything, and the error in the console is the following:

```
index.js:179 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'site' of undefined
at Object.component.destroy (index.js:179)
at Object.destroyComponent [as destroy] (ues-dashboards.js:93)
at destroyComponent (designer.js:449)
at designer.js:471
at async.js:567
at async.js:246
at async.js:122
at _each (async.js:46)
at async.each (async.js:121)
at _asyncMap (async.js:245)
```